# How to constraint scope of hasMany relationship in a query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am working on a laravel based project comprising of Authors, Posts and Comments as models.

The relationship between the models is as follows:
Author -> hasMany Post
Post -> hasMany Comment.

The problem is as follows:
Authors made multiple posts, and all of them have multiple comments. I want to get the count of the Authors with comments from internal members only on their latest post.

My Models are shown below-

Author.php

```
public function post() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function latestPost() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post', 'latest_post_id', 'id')-
 >orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Post.php

```
public function comment() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

The query I am using to get the data are as follow:

```
$author_count = Author::whereHas('latestPost.comment', function ($query) {
    $query->createdByInternal();
})->count();
```

When I execute this query, it considers all the Post models instead of only the latest Post and gives the authors who have a comment by an Internal member on any of their post.

However, on eager loading the latestPost query using "with" function, I get only the comments on the latest post.

```
$author = Author::with('latestPost.comment')->get();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Author::with(['latestPost','latestPost.comment'])->get();`

Comment: Please show the `scopeCreatedByInternal()` method from the `Comment` model.

Comment: `public scopeCreatedByInternal($query) {
        $query->whereNotNull('created_by_internal');
        return $query; 
    }`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count authors who have posts with no `created_by_internal 
 = null` comments, use [`whereDoesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence):

```
Author::whereDoesntHave('latestPost.comment', function ($query) {
    $query->notCreatedByInternal();
})
->count();
```

In the relationship definition put foreign key before the `id`:

```
public function latestPost()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post', 'latest_post_id', 'id')->latest();
}
```

Also, change to scope to:

```
public scopeNotCreatedByInternal($query)
{
    return $query->whereNull('created_by_internal');
}
```